# LaTex code for Polynomial Division in Ascending Powers

Tags: polynomials

[image: Please refer the image given below.]
Is there a way to let the LaTeX package Polynom also do division in *ascending* powers of *x* as given in the figure or any other package of LaTex is able to do this?

Comment: What? Are you talking about Latex? Are you referring to a specific package? Could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551)?

Comment: No, the package only uses descending order.

Comment: This should not have been closed. Please wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Also, if you downvote, please don't forget to revert the vote after the question is improved.

Comment: @egreg I know but I was hoping that just as you were once able to let it show $0x^{n}$ you might be able to work your magic once again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a feature request for a package that, in the current version, does not offer such a functionality.

Comment: 1. The example I gave _was_ in LaTeX.
2. I mentioned _specifically_ the package Polynom.
3. I gave a _MWE_ done by hand precisely because I could not do it otherwise.
4. egreg voted to close on Dec 28, 2015 because, he said, it was a feature request for a package. But you might also say that I was "just" asking for a hack to reverse the descending order of the package.
In any case, I still don't understand how it is `off topic', how I lacked `details and/or clarity'.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt It seems you are the only one who might consider. By the way, I just realized that it wasn't I who did the edit and, most importantly, the figure. I apologize for giving a false impression and am grateful to the Bot.